# XSLT Transformation: Combine multiple tags into single tag based on a condition

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

I have multiple tags in a node, I wan't to combine them into a single tag based on a condition.

Each person will have multiple JobInfo tags in sequence followed by multiple EmpInfo. I want to merge the 1st JobInfo with 1st EmpInfo and the 2nd JobInfo with 2nd EmpInfo only if the 'Applying' indicator is 'Y' and transform them as EmpJobInfo tag.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <soap:Body> 
 <App> 
 <person>
 <answerSet>
    <answers>
        <entry>
            <key>monthlyIncome</key>
            <value>1200</value>
        </entry>
    </answers>
    <answers>
        <entry>
            <key>Applying</key>
            <value>Y</value>
        </entry>
    </answers>
    <key>JobInfo</key>
 </answerSet>
 <answerSet>
    <answers>
        <entry>
            <key>monthlyIncome</key>
            <value>800</value>
        </entry>
    </answers>
    <answers>
        <entry>
            <key>Applying</key>
            <value>Y</value>
        </entry>
    </answers>
    <key>JobInfo</key>
</answerSet>
 <answerSet>
    <answers>
        <entry>
            <key>monthlyIncome</key>
            <value>450</value>
        </entry>
    </answers>
    <answers>
        <entry>
            <key>Applying</key>
            <value>N</value>
        </entry>
    </answers>
    <key>JobInfo</key>
</answerSet>
<answerSet>
    <answers>
        <entry>
            <key>EmpName</key>
            <value>Walmart</value>
        </entry>
    </answers>
    <key>EmpInfo</key>
</answerSet>
<answerSet>
    <answers>
        <entry>
            <key>EmpName</key>
            <value>Target</value>
        </entry>
    </answers>
    <key>EmpInfo</key>
</answerSet>
</person>
</App> 
</soap:Body> 
</soap:Envelope>
```

I'm currently using the below XSLT which will get the position of each tag and combine with other. But it doesn't check the 'Applying' is 'Y' or not.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:template match="*">
    <App>
      <xsl:for-each select="//person">
        <xsl:variable name ="person" select="." />
        <person>
          <xsl:for-each select="answerSet[key='EmpInfo']">
            <xsl:variable name ="pos" select="position()" />
            <answerSet>
              <xsl:copy-of select="answers" />
              <xsl:copy-of select="$person/answerSet[key='JobInfo'][$pos]/answers" />
              <key>EmpJobInfo</key>
            </answerSet>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </person>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </App>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and the expected output is

```
<App>
  <person>
    <answerSet>
      <answers>
        <entry>
          <key>EmpName</key>
          <value>Walmart</value>
        </entry>
      </answers>
      <answers>
        <entry>
          <key>monthlyIncome</key>
          <value>1200</value>
        </entry>
      </answers>
      <key>EmpJobInfo</key>
    </answerSet>
    <answerSet>
      <answers>
        <entry>
          <key>EmpName</key>
          <value>Target</value>
        </entry>
      </answers>
      <answers>
        <entry>
          <key>monthlyIncome</key>
          <value>800</value>
        </entry>
      </answers>
      <key>EmpJobInfo</key>
    </answerSet>
  </person>
</App>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to process the elements for which your condition holds then I think changing the template to

```
<xsl:template match="App">
    <App>
        <xsl:for-each select="//person">
            <xsl:variable name ="person" select="." />
            <person>
                <xsl:for-each select="answerSet[key='JobInfo'][answers/entry[key = 'Applying']/value = 'Y']">
                    <xsl:variable name ="pos" select="position()" />
                    <answerSet>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="$person/answerSet[key='EmpInfo'][$pos]/answers" />
                        <xsl:copy-of select="answers[not(entry[key = 'Applying']/value = 'Y')]" />
                        <key>EmpJobInfo</key>
                    </answerSet>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </person>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </App>
</xsl:template>
```

should implement that condition.